# regex to find div tags

Tags: regex

I need a regex that will find either an opening div tag, or a closing div tag, or both in an html web page. Thanks :)

Comment: Oh no, not again. -.- http://tinyurl.com/yzep3mp

Comment: That won't get old anytime soon.

Answer (score 4):

Just to be safe:

```
</? *div[^>]*>
```

Comment: I wouldn't describe that as "safe".

Answer (score 1):

You could start with:

```
</?div>
```

This won't correctly handle:

- whitespace
- attributes on the div
- self-closing div tags
- upper case tags
- tags inside HTML comments that should be ignored
- etc...

To handle HTML correctly you're better off using an HTML parser rather than regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use [xpath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/) it would be `//div`  Look into using an XML parser that supports it instead of regex.  If you MUST use regex, go with coding_hero's answer.

Just for show, in PHP:

```
//$htmldoc is some xhtml document from somewhere
$xhtml = simplexml_load_file($htmldoc);
$divs = $xhtml->xpath('//div'); //grab simpleXMLElement from all divs in document
return $divs->asXML(); //returns xml of div elements and children
```

Comment: I believe XPath requires XML content. HTML does not conform to all of the rules of XML.

Comment: Agreed, but that's why I prefaced this with "if it must be regex, use coding_hero's".  I also specified that it's based on an xhtml document.  SimpleXML is also fully compatible with DOM in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

[HTML, XHTML, and XML can not be parsed using regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). There are parsers designed for this type of thing. If you specify the language(s) you are using, I'm sure someone can suggest the right tool(s) for the job, but I know for a fact that regular expressions will not be on that list.

Comment: He/she said he/she wants to find the tags, not necessarily parse the contents.

Comment: It doesn't matter what you want to do - most parsers that I've seen allow you do to things like count tags too. But regex is never the right answer when dealing with HTML.

Answer (score 0):

To find opening and closing div tag I would use

> ```
> </?\bdiv\b[^>]*>
> ```